# String with new line and tabs to display in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I have a string coming from my java backend which is formatted to display in a certain way, the new line, tab and space characters are in certain positions.

How do I get this to display the same way in HTML?

For example, say I have the current string in Javascript as so:

`var str = "\t\tTitle \n Some text \t\t\t more text";`

Comment: Are you sure you don't have them with backslashes?

Answer (score 6):

Browsers typically strip out extra white space, you might need to put it inside a preformatted text block or use [`white-space: pre`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space)

```
var pre = document.createElement("pre");
pre.innerHTML = str;
document.appendChild(pre);
```

Also yes, you need to use backslahes too, as mentioned about.

Comment: @Juan Mendes Cool! I totally didn't know about the white-space: pre thing, gonna go check that out!

Answer (score 1):

I might be late but just in order to help if a beginner like me is facing this kind of problem.

You can add a css class to the html tag where you want to display the data. In my case I am using ngFor of Angular 2. The data coming from my back end had line breaks and tabs. So I just added a class to the html tag with a css white-spacing style as follows.

Backend Data`"title": "postIssueResponse() {\n\tthis.parent.postIssueResponse(this.issueId, this.newResponse);\n console.log(this.newResponse);\n  this.newResponse \u003d \"\";\n}"`

```
<p class="response-title">{{myData?.title}}</p>
```

And the css

```
.response-title {
white-space:pre;
```

}

This one do the job perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `textarea` also. here is a [Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/49shLqhf/1/)

[MDN textarea](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea)

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
white-space: pre-wrap;
```

as it also prevents overflow